# PUT VS PATCH for operation set template to default

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I have to change one value (template) in my entity A:

```
class A {
private Template template
}
```

My endpoint looks like:
`/warehouse/company/{companyId}/template/default`

with body:

```
class MyDto {
private Long templateId
}
```

What is the best solution for this operation? I want to change only one value in my entity: based on `MyDto` I have to fetch template from DB and set `A.setTemplate(newTemplateFromDB)`.

The best option would be `PATCH` without `RequestBody`, but request body is necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use `PATCH` because you are partially updating your resource (`A`) and not completely updating it.
If you would update the complete resource by replacing your DB data with whatever you receive in the endpoint, then you should use `PUT`.

I just don't get why you say that the best option would be without the request body.